# Pre-populating form fields with the row data by clicking on the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Please help if you are seeing this.I want to pre-populate the form-field with row data after clicking on the same row.
**SIMILAR TO THIS DEMO:**http://jsbin.com/qavugo/2/edit?html,js,output

Problem is faced now. fillForm() function is OK(**AS SHOWN IN THE DEMO** inside the scripts) in order to populate the form field with  row data.**HOW DO I GET ROW DATA**? But as I am populating the table using jsp like this

```
<table class="data-table" id="test" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Student ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Year Level</td>
    </tr>
    <c:foreach items="${allStudents}" var="stud">
        <tr>
            <td>${stud.studentId}</td>
            <td>${stud.firstname}</td>
            <td>${stud.lastname}</td>
            <td>${stud.yearLevel}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:foreach>
</table>
```

Which makes it more difficult for me for **getting the rowData** than what is ***showed in the DEMO***.

MY FORM

```
<form name="frm" class="data-form" action="./StudentServlet" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Student ID --></label><input type="text" name="studentId" value="${student.studentId}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>First Name --></label><input type="text" name="firstname" value="${student.firstname}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Last Name --></label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="${student.lastname}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Year Level --></label><input type="text" name="yearLevel" value="${student.yearLevel}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

THE SCRIPTS

```
$(function() {
    // I am not  using dummy data here.
    var rowData = [
        // how and what should go here.Please help
    ];
    row.on("click", function() {
        fillForm(rowData);
    });
    return row;
});

$(".data-table").append(rows);

function fillForm(rowData) {
    var form = $(".data-form");
    form.find("input.value1").val(rowData.value1);
    form.find("input.value2").val(rowData.value2);
    form.find("input.value3").val(rowData.value3);
    form.find("input.value4").val(rowData.value4);
}
```

I am updating the records like this

```
     <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add"  />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value=Refresh  />
                </td>    
            </tr>       
        </table>
```

I am getting an error after clicking the/add/edit/delete  button

```
       Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[StudentServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet    StudentServlet threw exception

         java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "                                                                                                                     "

  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
   at com.joseph.controller.StudentServlet.processRequest(StudentServlet.java:35)
   at com.joseph.controller.StudentServlet.doPost(StudentServlet.java:99)
```

Comment: Hi, Rohit Roy. It seems that second issue you are describing is completely unrelated to your original question, which was about populating input values automatically. Now, you would need to provide way more information in order for us to be able to help you, mainly, what methods you are calling on each of your "Add", "Edit", "Delete", and "Refresh" inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That demo looks way too complicated for the task at hand. There's really no need to work with class references. You could simplify your approach by doing the following:

### HTML:

```
<h1>Student Info:</h1>
<form class="data-form">
    <label>Student ID
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>First Name
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>Last Name
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>Year Level
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
</form>

<table class="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Year Level</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>Sinatra</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Miles</td>
        <td>Davis</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>Waits</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td", this).on("click", function () {
        var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
            $($(".data-form input")[i]).val($(v).text());
        });
    });
});
```

The only condition for this to work is that the input order in the form needs to match the column order in the table. Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/me9t13s5/) for reference.

Comment: Yeah!! It worked.Thanx Marventus,you made my day.May the force be with you.

Comment: Good to know! Please don't forget to mark at least one of the provided answers as correct.

Comment: Oops,Sorry I forgot.DONE :)

Comment: I am getting error!! after I tried to update the records.It went well till populating the form field.Why is it happening??I am not able to understand.Please help .thanks.I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR Form (data-form)tag includes your edit/delete/ update inputs.Keep that out of your form tag.Then the java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "  will not take place.See if it works.**

I tried adding the code further as mentioned above.It did not worked well.I am facing same dilemma.Anyone plz tell where is it going wrong?

```
   <script>
  $(function() 
  row.on("click", function() {
    $('INPUT', this).each(function(i){
     rowData['value' + (i+1)] = this.value;
    });
   fillForm(rowData);
   });

  function fillForm(rowData) {
  var form = $(".data-form");
  form.find("input.value1").val(rowData.value1);
  form.find("input.value2").val(rowData.value2);
  form.find("input.value3").val(rowData.value3);
   form.find("input.value4").val(rowData.value4);
 } 
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the on.cick function

```
    row.on("click", function() {
      $('INPUT', this).each(function(i){
        rowData['value' + (i+1)] = this.value;
      });
      fillForm(rowData);
    });
```

Comment: Please mark as correct and select this as the answer if it resolved your problem.